# Which is the best pagination for displaying mysql records

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I have an application where users fetch records for reporting purpose.
But i'm confused between using jquery pagination and mysql pagination (LIMIT, OFFSET).

Because jquery pagination needs all records without limit so that pagination takes place at client side and this may slow down the query.

Where mysql can use limit (i'm using codeigniter framework) but every time i click on pagination it will ping for database for getting next set of data and also mysql pagination is creating duplicate records.

Is there a good and fast way to pagination, If yes, Please suggest me.

Thank You......

Comment: what do you mean by mysql pagination is creating duplicate records?

Comment: If there is record A, record B, record C, record D in first page again in second page record C, record D, record E, record F is appeared where C and D is repeated.

Comment: please post your query and controller section

Comment: It is better to restrict the result at server side by limiting the records in sql query. It helps to your database and reduce the loading time for the users when viewing the page.

Comment: Check out the user guide for CodeIgniter, it has built in Pagination class.

Comment: @Arnelle Balane, yes i'm using codeigniter's pagination

Comment: Use CI pagination class it will be very easy check out the below example.

Answer (score 0):

I did pagination in this way......

```
public function page($category_id)
{

$result = $this->model_file->model_function($category_id);

$start_index = 0;

$total_rows = count($result);

$items_per_page = 10;

$filtered = array_splice($result,$start_index,$items_per_page);

$model['data'] = $filtered;

$model['page_link'] = create_page_links (base_url()."/controller_file_name/page", $items_per_page, $total_rows);

$this->load->view('view_file_name_path',$model);

}

function create_page_links($base_url, $per_page, $total_rows) {

$CI = & get_instance();
$CI->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = $base_url;
$config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;
$config['per_page'] = $per_page; 

$CI->pagination->initialize($config); 

return $CI->pagination->create_links();

}
```